# Lambda : Perform order by but refer to the included table

Tags: c#, lambda

This is my current lambda expression:

```
var field = db.forms
                   .Include(r => r.lists)
                   .Include(r => r.fields)
                   .Include(r => r.workflow_step
                           .Select(b => b.fields))
                   .FirstOrDefault(r => r.form_id == ID);
```

What I need to do is to sort or perform order by clause using the fields."column name" like `.OrderBy(s=>fields.step_field_no)`

it seems that order by is only available for the fields available in db.forms.

I've tried the following code below.

```
    var field = (db.forms
           .Include(r => r.lists)
           .Include(r => r.workflow_step)
           .Include(r => r.fields)
           .Include(r => r.workflow_step
                   .Select(b => b.fields))
           .Include(r=>r.fields
               .OrderBy(c=>c.step_field_no))
           .FirstOrDefault(r => r.form_id == ID));
```

But during runtime, it throws an error:

> "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties.\r\nParameter name: path"

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're attempting to do. _"it seems that order by is only available for the fields available in db.forms"_ -- you can call `OrderBy()` using whatever data is available at the point where you call it. If you are trying to call it after the `.Select()` in the above, you should be able to order by `f => f.step_field_no`. If you are trying to call it before the `.Select()`, then `b => b.fields.step_field_no` instead. I don't see any context above where `s => fields.step_field_no` would work; where would `fields` come from?

Comment: Hi Peter, Ive tried the code below,                                               
               db.forms
                   .Include(r => r.lists)
                   .Include(r => r.fields).OrderBy(s => field.step_field_no)
                   .Include(r => r.workflow_step)                                              
                           .Select(b => b.fields))
                   .FirstOrDefault(r => r.form_id == ID)  this one doesn't sort the result according to step field no. Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft documents says the Include parameter is a string.  See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx.  How can you do an OrderBy on a single string.  OrderBy needs to be done on an array,

Comment: What exactly is your end goal? Do you want the `var field` to contain sorted values? Understand that `.Include` and `.Include(x => x.Select())` are for eager loading and not for `specifying row order`. I have a feeling that you want to apply the `.OrderBy` after the last `.Include`. But you need to represent your question better

Comment: Hi @Vikhram, My goal is to sort the result according to dbo.[fields].[step_field_no].